# Laravel - Insert a model multiple times

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I have a model that I change some attributes I want to insert it but Eloquent, after the first save() will automatically do an update while I'm using save() method, here is my code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $range; $i++) {
  $model->attr = "Some new value";
  $model->save(); // after the first save() will do update but I want to an insert
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations#database-seeding
Might come in handy.

Comment: @RobinValk Not what I'm searching for

Comment: can you please explain clearly what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of the Model every time you loop through. Try this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $range; $i++) {
  $model = new Product;
  $model->attr = "Some new value";
  $model->save(); // after the first save() will do update but I want to an insert
}
```

I am not sure what your Model name is but I used Product in this instance. Replace this with your Model name.

Comment: The problem that this model has many attributes, so I'm searching a way to just change some attr and save

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by this. Could you explain it into some more detail or in another way.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `create`

```
$attributes = [
    'foo' => 'bar'
];
for ($i = 0; $i < $range; $i++) {
    $attributes['foo'] = 'bar'.$i;
    Model::create($attributes);
}
```

Or if you want create a function in your model:

```
public function saveAsNew(){
    $this->exists = false;
    $this->attributes[$this->primaryKey] = null; // reset the id
    return $this->save();
}
```

---

Also I wrote this function, that saves the same model multiple times (yes I know that's not what your after but I wanted to post it anyways:

```
public function saveMultiple($times){
    $saved = true;
    for($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++){
        if(!$this->save()){
            $saved = false;
        }
        $this->attributes[$this->primaryKey] = null; // unset the id
        $this->exists = false;
    }

    return $saved;
}
```